# How to identify ISV model for partner org?

Tags: isv, partner-portal

I have query related to Salesforce ISV partner program as follows:

How to identify which ISV model default or applied for partner org?

While creating partner org it asked for AppExchange Partner Program or Cloud Alliance Partner Program. And AppExchange Partner Program have two models i.e. ISVForce and Force.com Embbed(OEM). Got from this link http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/

Now after Partner registration, How to become ISVForce or OEM partner?

Same question on StackExchange:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900138/how-to-identify-isv-model-for-partner-org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to login to the [salesforce partner portal](https://sites.secure.force.com/partners/PP2PartnerLoginPage?) and file a case to get clarification on your partner type.

Comment: Ryan is right. You should log a case to get the answer.